# Adding objects into JTable rows

Tags: java, swing, calendar

I am currently working on a project where one of my parts is to create an interactive calendar that adds events into the calendar on actual date. Every object is added into an array. The calendar also have prev/next week functions where the dates will change to prev/next week. But when I go back one week, and then goes one week forward the calendar only contains one of the objects from my array.

This is the code for adding objects into rows after changing week:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        column = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < 91; j++) {
            e = events[week][j];
            if (e != null) {
                date = df.format(e.getDate());
                if (date.equals(days[i])) {
                    for (int k = 1; k < 14; k++) {
                        if (isRowEmpty(k, i)) {
                            model.setValueAt(e.getName(), k, column);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            } 
            //this is where things go wrong
        }
    }
```

This is where I add objects into the calendar and into the array:

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String date = df.format(e.getDate());
    int row;
    int column;
    int weekNumber = findWeekNumber(e.getDate());

    for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++) {
        if (events[weekNumber+1][i] == null) {
            events[weekNumber+1][i] = e;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        column = new Integer(i);
        if (date.equals(days[i])) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 14; j++) {
                if (isRowEmpty(j, i)) {
                    model.setValueAt(e.getName(), j, column);
                    return true;
                }//end of inner if 
            }//end of inner for
        }//end of if
    }//end of for
    return false;
}//end of method
```

I really hope someone can spot the mistake, I've beens staring at this code for so long that I think I'm lost in javalimbo.

Also, I'll add pictures of how my calendar looks like:

[image]

Comment: "*But when I go back one week, and then goes one week forward the calendar only contains one of the objects from my array.*" And we have no code related to that problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been working on this code up till now and I finally figured it out. All is good now!